# Get files list with two extensions like deb|rpm|txt

Tags: shell, cron, rm

I'd like to remove `*.(deb|rpm)` files from my `Downloads` folder on my Ubuntu machine every hour.

I have this on my crontab

```
* */1 * * * cd /home/alexalannunes/Downloads && ls *.deb > log.txt && rm  *.deb
```

'Cause I want a log of which files have been removed.

But this line removes only `*.deb`. I want to remove files with `(.deb|.rmp|.other_file)`

It's possible?

I tried to search in google but I didn't find anything

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can specify as many extensions as you want, just list them separately. E.g.:

```
* */1 * * * cd /home/alexalannunes/Downloads && ls *.deb *.rpm > log.txt && rm  *.deb *.rpm
```

Comment: didn't Work! :( 

```ls *.deb *.rpm```

ls: unable to access '* .deb': File or directory does not exist

Comment: I found it  wooooooooooooooow

```ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}```

Comment: @AlexAlanNunes you can safely ignore the error. In fact, `ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}` is _exactly_ the same as `ls *.mp3 *.exe *.mp4`, there is no difference. The shell will expand `*.{mp3,exe,mp4}` to `*.mp3 *.exe *.mp4` before calling `ls`, so both will run the exact same command.

Comment: But in all cases `ls ... && rm` won’t delete *anything* if any of the extensions fail to match. `nullglob` would avoid that but it would end up being confusing when *no* extensions match: `ls` would list all files, and `rm` would fail.

Comment: `rm -f` will make rm to no longer complain

Answer (score 4):

If the shell supports in which the crontab runs suppports brace expansions, you can give multiple extensions by using brace expansion:

```
*.{rpm,deb,other_file}
```

Otherwise just chain multiple extensions.

```
*.rpm *.deb
```

Also, you don't need a separate `ls`, `rm` has verbose output with `-v` and you should add `-f` to ignore nonexistent files and arguments and never prompt.

```
* */1 * * * rm -fv /home/alexalannunes/Downloads/*.{deb,rpm} > log.txt
```

or

```
* */1 * * * rm -fv /home/alexalannunes/Downloads/*.deb /home/alexalannunes/Downloads/*.rpm > log.txt
```